# Configure Circle CI for project in sub directory

Tags: circleci

I have a project that has two directories in it; each one essentially a node project. I want to run my unit tests for project A from Circle CI when a PR opens. From what I've read, the circle.yml file has to live in the root of the project. What I want to do is just change directory first, and then do all of the normal circle actions from project A directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what ended up working for me was adding

```
general:
  build_dir: project-a
```

to my circle file. That was the only change I needed to make.

Comment: Where exactly did you put this in your `config.yml` ? thanks.

Comment: Not valid in CircleCi 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of Circle CI [2.0](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/) and later `build_dir` is replaced by `working_directory` so you can use it in your `config.yml` as following

```
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/sub-folder
    environment:
      FOO: bar
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Running tests
          command: make test
```

More details over [here](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#jobs)